# Converting List (Maybe a) to Maybe (List a) in Elm

Tags: algorithm, list, elm, option-type

What's a good way to convert `List (Maybe a)` to `Maybe (List a)` in Elm?

The logic is simple:

- return `Just (List a)` if all items are `Just a`
- otherwise, return `Nothing`.

```
Example 1:

input:  [ Just 1, Just 2, Just 3 ]
output: Just [ 1, 2, 3 ]

Example 2:

input:  [ Just 1, Nothing, Just 3 ]
output: Nothing
```

Can it be done easily with some of the built-in functions?

The best I came up with looks like this:

```elm
listOfMaybesToMaybeList : List (Maybe a) -> Maybe (List a)
listOfMaybesToMaybeList listOfMaybes =
    List.foldl
        (\maybeItem ->
            \maybeResultList ->
                case ( maybeItem, maybeResultList ) of
                    ( Just item, Just resultList ) ->
                        Just (List.append resultList [ item ])

                    ( _, _ ) ->
                        Nothing
        )
        (Just [])
        listOfMaybes
```

And what would be an appropriate name for this kind of function? As I was searching for an answer, I saw that there's a function called `sequence` in Haskell which seems to be doing something similar.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this could at least explain why the downvote. Otherwise I’ll never learn my mistake.

Comment: Sure, it's too broad because it asks multiple vague questions, partly opinion-based and fits much better in [codereview.se]. See [ask] and [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: I see your point, however I’m not sure it fits much better in code review, because I don’t want anyone to review my code. But I do see that if you thought so, there’s probably some fault in the way I expressed myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the Elm Fancy Search tool and search on the function signature: [List (Maybe a) -> Maybe (List a)](https://klaftertief.github.io/elm-search/?q=List%20(Maybe%20a)%20->%20Maybe%20(List%20a))

The first result turns up [Maybe.Extra.combine](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/maybe-extra/latest/Maybe-Extra#combine)

Comment: Looks like their implementation is similar to mine

Answer (score 6):

@Chad Gilbert's answer sure is correct, but if you're looking for a simpler implementation of such a function, then the following line will do the trick:

```
listOfMaybesToMaybeList : List (Maybe a) -> Maybe (List a)
listOfMaybesToMaybeList listOfMaybes =
    List.foldr (Maybe.map2 (::)) (Just []) listOfMaybes
```

Or just:

```
listOfMaybesToMaybeList : List (Maybe a) -> Maybe (List a)
listOfMaybesToMaybeList = List.foldr (Maybe.map2 (::)) (Just [])
```

[Maybe.map2](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Maybe#map2) just takes a function and two `Maybe` values and applies the function to the values:

```
> Maybe.map2 (+) (Just 2) (Just 3)
Just 5 : Maybe.Maybe number
> Maybe.map2 (::) (Just 2) (Just [1])
Just [2,1] : Maybe.Maybe (List number)
```

Note, that `(::)` function (prepend to the list) is used instead of `(++)` or `List.append` because it's more performant for the lists. Then `foldr` must be used instead of `foldl` to retain the order.

Comment: Thanks, I didn’t know about the performance difference. And nice use of built-in functions!